# How to search channel fields

Tags: search, channel, low-search, supersearch

I have constructed a real estate site that has a channel containing property entries, each of which have several channel fields, such as price, number of bedrooms, year built, location (state), property id, etc..

It is my objective to create a search form where the user can perform a search to locate properties. The form will have inputs where the user can select an number of parameters such as a price range, minimum number of bedrooms, a state. When they click the submit button, the resulting page will list properties that meet the user's search criteria.

EE's core search seems VERY limited in that it can only search entry metadata like titles, authors or date published. To accomplish my search requirement, I might need to invest in something like Solespace Super Search. I don't have a problem with that but I would like to know if anybody has constructed anything similar with Super Search or Low Search or something else. I have not used these add-ons and cannot determine from the documentation of it possible. It seems so but I would like to hear from someone who has done something similar. I also know there is a free plugin called Search Fields, but is appears limited in what it can do.

I'm also looking at implementing an EE exp:query. I have not used query before and wonder if it can perform the operation I want. I've created db queries using CodeIgniter and wonder if this sort of database query is possible within EE.

Thanks for any suggestions.

I have tried using the EE Search but I don't see any way to limit a search to only one field.

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="news" search_in="entries"}
<p>
 <label for="keywords">Search:</label><br>
 <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" size="18" maxlength="100">
</p>
<p>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
 </p>
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

This will search channel fields that have been designated searchable, however there seems no way to limit the search to a specific field, for example price over or between.

Comment: Super Search and Low Search are both great products, but... what are you talking about? Every default field type is searchable.

Comment: I know for a fact that Low Search has been used for real estate/property directory searches, so definitely possible with LS. Check the list of example sites using Low Search: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search